# upload image to webapp/image directory from localhost via jsp

Tags: spring, jsp

i want to upload image using browse option from jsp page to webapp directory of spring mvc structure.

//jsp button for browse

```
<label for="picture">Picture</label>
         <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image"/>       
                    <input type='file' id="imgInp"/>
```

I don't know how to do it.
Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "uploadPic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadPic(
        @RequestParam(value = "file") final MultipartFile file) {
    try {           
       file.renameTo(new File("newResourceFolderHere\\" + file.getName()));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "site";
}
```

And in html, you would use the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="urlPrefix/uploadPic" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Upload picture</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
</form>
```